# How can I GROUP BY SELECT subquery aggregates?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, subquery

first time on here, hoping for help. (MySQL) I tried to use subqueries in a SELECT statement but when I GROUP BY, the single aggregate value outputs of the subqueries just produce the one same value for all rows in the table. This implies they are not GROUPED, right? How close am I to getting this right? Thanks

```
SELECT 
  c.name, ca.name, DATE_FORMAT(sp.created,'%Y%m') AS yr_month,
  ss.signup_source, count(sp.seller_profile_id) AS No_seller_profiles,    
  (SELECT SUM(seller_invoice.gbp_value)/100 
     FROM seller_invoice JOIN seller_profile 
       ON seller_invoice.seller_profile_id = seller_profile.seller_profile_id 
     WHERE seller_invoice.created BETWEEN seller_profile.created AND ADDDATE(seller_profile.created, INTERVAL 30 DAY)),
  (SELECT count(project_response.project_response_id) 
     FROM project_response JOIN seller_profile 
       ON project_response.seller_profile_id = seller_profile.seller_profile_id 
     WHERE project_response.created BETWEEN seller_profile.created AND ADDDATE(seller_profile.created, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND project_response.is_visible_to_seller = 1)
FROM seller_profile AS sp 
JOIN country AS c ON sp.country_id = c.country_id
JOIN seller_category AS sc ON sp.seller_profile_id = sc.seller_profile_id
JOIN category AS ca ON sc.category_id = ca.category_id
JOIN seller_signup_source AS ss ON sp.seller_profile_id = ss.seller_profile_id
WHERE sp.created BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-12-31'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;
```

Comment: `GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,6,7`?

Comment: Thanks Nick but that doesn't seem to work...

Comment: I would really appreciate help from anybody on this! Thank yoy

Comment: Without seeing some sample data exhibiting the problem including what result you expected and what you actually got it's going to be very hard for anyone to help debug this. Can you create a demo on dbfiddle.uk or db-fiddle.com?